# Attempting to Automate creation of Programmatic IAM User in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I have to create a fair handful of programmatic users for tool access into my AWS environment and I thought it would be useful to create a function to distribute to each account.

The purpose is to trigger a one-time creation of a IAM user with programmatic access, and store the keys in the Secrets Manager all while keeping the keys as hidden as possible (i.e. none in the function, none in logging, and none in transit) until landing in Secrets Manager.

I have set the lambda permissions for this specific function to deny the generation of CloudWatch or CloudTrail logs (which seems to be functioning properly through testing). However, the creation of the secret is giving me issues that I can't seem to solve. Below is my script:

```
import boto3, json
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    iam_client = boto3.client('iam')

    user_name = 'tenable-cc-test'
    policy_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess'
    
    account_id = boto3.client("sts").get_caller_identity()["Account"]

    try:
        user = iam_client.create_user(
            UserName=user_name,
            Tags=[
                {
                    'Key': 'donotdelete',
                    'Value': 'yes'
                }
            ]
        )
    except ClientError as error:
        if error.response['Error']['Code'] == 'EntityAlreadyExists':
            return 'User {0} is already available'.format(user_name)
        else:
            return 'Unexpected error occurred... User {0} could not be created'.format(user_name)

    try:
        iam_client.attach_user_policy(
            UserName=user_name,
            PolicyArn=policy_arn
        )
    except ClientError as error:
        print('Unexpected error occurred while attaching policy... cleaning up', error)
        iam_client.delete_user(UserName=user_name)
        return 'User could not be created', error

    try:
        access_secrete_key = iam_client.create_access_key(
            UserName=user_name
        )
    except ClientError as error:
        print('Unexpected error occurred while creating access key... cleaning up')
        iam_client.detach_user_policy(
            UserName= user_name,
            PolicyArn= policy_arn
        )
        iam_client.delete_user(UserName=user_name)
        return 'User could not be created', error

    print('User {0} has been created successfully'.format(user_name))

    access_key = access_secrete_key['AccessKey']['AccessKeyId']
    secret_key = access_secrete_key['AccessKey']['SecretAccessKey']

    sm = boto3.client('secretsmanager')

    sm.create_secret(
        Name='tenable-cc-keys',
        #ClientRequestToken='string',
        Description='Keys for tenable-cc user.',
        #KmsKeyId='string',
        #SecretBinary=b'bytes',
        SecretString={
            'username': 'access_key',
            'password': 'secret_key'
        },
        Tags=[
            {
                'Key': 'donotdelete',
                'Value': 'yes'
            },
        ]
    )
    
    print('Account:', account_id)
    print('Access Key:', access_key)
    print('Secret Key:', secret_key)
```

The error that I am receiving is:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter SecretString, value: {'username': 'access_key', 'password': 'secret_key'}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'str'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 72, in lambda_handler\n    'Value': 'yes'\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 357, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 649, in _make_api_call\n    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 697, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    api_params, operation_model)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 297, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"
  ]
}
```

I have tried all manner of variations that I could think of for the SecretString, removed unused descriptors, commented them out, left them available. All lead me to similar errors. I have poured over the following documentation and I believe I am missing something very simple. Also, no matter what I have tried, it continues to tell me that my Parameter class is 'dict' when it needs to be 'string', I am simply following the format in the aws documentation.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html

Can anyone offer some council? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SecretString](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html#SecretsManager.Client.create_secret) should be **string**, not a dictionary. One way to do this, is to covert your dict to json string, using `json.dumps`:

```
SecretString=json.dumps({
            'username': 'access_key',
            'password': 'secret_key'
        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer worked! Thanks Marcin.

I also got it working with a different method below:

```
    sm= boto3.client('secretsmanager')
    
    sm.create_secret(
        Name='tenable-user-keys',
        #ClientRequestToken='string',
        Description='Tenable CC User keys.',
        #KmsKeyId='string',
        #SecretBinary=b'bytes',
        SecretString="{\"Access Key\":\" %s \",\"Secret Key\":\" %s \"}" % (access_key, secret_key),
        Tags=[
            {
                'Key': 'donotdelete',
                'Value': 'yes'
            },
        ]
    )
```

For anyone curious!

Answer (score 0):

> Problem statement :

To create session token that are valid for longer duration so that end user can upload the file to S3 bucket.

> Approach :

(*) When a project is onboarded create a IAM user with accesskey, secret and attach a policy to this user that allow upload of file to S3 bucket.

(*) When a project is completed delete the IAM user based on its username.

**1. Create IAM user to upload file to S3**
[image]

**IAM policy for IAM role to create user:**

User should be able to use an access key ID and a secret access key.

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateUser",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateUser",
                "iam:CreateAccessKey",
                "iam:PutUserPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is trust relationship for all role below

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Above IAM policy -> IAM role → lambda  →  create IAM user

**Security :** "iam:PutUserPolicy"  lambda code will add inline policy to restrict access to specific S3 bucket.

**Note :**
Reason for "Resource": "*"  is since IAM user is yet to be created and in advance we don’t know the ARN.

Reason for iam:PutUserPolicylater in the code we will assign policy with dynamic S3 bucket name.

**Lambda to create IAM user with a upload permission to S3 bucket**

**Security :** Inline policy in below lambda code will grant least privileges to IAM user to upload file to specific S3 bucket only.

```html
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(context, event):
    
    # Create an IAM client
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    
    #Prefix is "abc-user-* and will be stored in DB after successful creation
    UserName = 'abc-user-XXXXXXXXXXXX' 
    bucket_name = #Todo # read from DB

    # Create a new IAM user
    response = client.create_user(UserName=UserName)
    
    # Create access key for the user
    access_key_response = client.create_access_key(UserName=UserName)
    access_key_id = access_key_response['AccessKey']['AccessKeyId']
    secret_access_key = access_key_response['AccessKey']['SecretAccessKey']
    
    # Create an IAM policy to allow upload to the specified bucket
    policy_document = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AllowS3Upload",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": ["s3:PutObject", "s3:CreateMultipartUpload"],
                "Resource": "f"arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*"
            }
        ]
    }
    
    # Attach the policy to the user
    client.put_user_policy(UserName=UserName, PolicyName='S3UploadPolicy', PolicyDocument=json.dumps(policy_document))
```

**2. Delete IAM user**
[image]

**IAM policy for IAM role to delete user with cascading effect**

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteUser",
                "iam:DeleteUserPolicy",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
                "iam:ListUserPolicies",
                "iam:ListAttachedUserPolicies",
                "iam:DetachUserPolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::account-no:user/abc-user-*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note :**

Above policy will make sure to delete user that start with prefix abc-user-* but the complete user name name will be passed from lambda function.

We need list permission on ListAccessKeys, ListUserPolicies,  and ListAttachedUserPoliciesbecause given a userName we could retrieve all it’s keys, policies information.

DetachUserPolicy and DeleteUserPolicywill detach and delete given user policy only. It won’t have effect on other user policy.

**Cascade delete IAM user in AWS**

To perform a cascade delete of an IAM user in AWS, you need to delete :

user's access keys

inline policies

attached managed policies

finally the user itself

Here's an example Python code snippet that demonstrates how to perform a cascade delete of an IAM user using boto3:

```html
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Create an IAM client
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    
    # Specify the IAM user to delete
    username = #Todo read from DB
    
    # Delete the user's access keys
    response = client.list_access_keys(UserName=username)
    access_keys = response['AccessKeyMetadata']
    for access_key in access_keys:
        client.delete_access_key(UserName=username, AccessKeyId=access_key['AccessKeyId'])
      
    # Delete the user's inline policies
    response = client.list_user_policies(UserName=username)
    policy_names = response['PolicyNames']
    for policy_name in policy_names:
        client.delete_user_policy(UserName=username, PolicyName=policy_name)
    
    # Detach and delete the user's attached managed policies
    response = client.list_attached_user_policies(UserName=username)
    attached_policies = response['AttachedPolicies']
    for policy in attached_policies:
        policy_arn = policy['PolicyArn']
        client.detach_user_policy(UserName=username, PolicyArn=policy_arn)
        client.delete_policy(PolicyArn=policy_arn)
    
    # Delete the IAM user
    client.delete_user(UserName=username)
```

Answer (score 0):

To secure lambda from assigning any random policy(permission) to user; you can do below:

Create a below policy(Let's say policy-1) one time:--- Refer : [AWS Policy variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) for ${aws:username}

```html
{{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::abc-dev-${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Create a IAM role (Let's say Role-1) for lambda with below IAM policy (Let's say policy-2) attached:

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "createNewIAMUser",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateUser",
                "iam:CreateAccessKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "attachPolicyToUserToUpload",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AttachUserPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "iam:PolicyArn": "replace with ARN of above policy"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then lambda will be as showed below:

```html
import boto3
import os
import json


def lambda_handler(context, event):
    
    # Create an IAM client
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    
    # Create a new IAM user
    response = client.create_user(UserName='abc-user-1')
    
    # Create access key for the user
    access_key_response = client.create_access_key(UserName='abc-user-1')
    print("access_key_response---",access_key_response)
    access_key = access_key_response['AccessKey']
    
    # Print the access key details
    print(f"Access Key ID: {access_key['AccessKeyId']}")
    print(f"Secret Access Key: {access_key['SecretAccessKey']}")
       
     
    response = client.attach_user_policy(
        UserName='abc-user-1',
        PolicyArn= 'add-here-policy-1-arn'
    )
```